# Change family status in Germany without visiting Kreisverwaltungsreferat

Tags: germany, taxes

I've divorced not that long ago and now, being a Germany resident I need to change my tax status - for that I need to change my family status first (I'm living with my son from first marriage). 
I've written letters to KVR but they all left unanswered so far, so I'm asking here:

**Is there any way to register new family status without visiting KVR?**

Not only it's time consuming and recently it's very hard to get online appointment but it's just that it's last thing I want to do now  - to visit a very crowded place in the middle of COVID-19 outbreak.

Answer (score 2):

Assumption: With **Kreisverwaltungsreferat** I assume you mean the local registration office, which in different areas, has different names.

The local registration office is where you report your changed status, but you must also apply for the change of the tax class at the tax office (Finanzamt).

The link below offers a PDF Application form for this purpose.

---

**Sources**:

- [Die Steuerklasse beim Finanzamt ändern – so geht's](https://www.steuerklassen.com/lohnsteuerklassen/steuerklasse-beim-finanzamt-aendern/)

Comment: Mark, thank you for this answer. Just to clarify - I've been told that I just can not change my tax class in this particular case before changing the family status - is it incorrect? Yep, in a registration office - good to know that it has different names in different areas by the way ))

Comment: @shabunc To be frank, my first version of the answer stated that. But since the site says that this can be done before the divorce is effected. The Finanzamt does extract / check information from the registry office. So it is probably a combination of both. If you will be reverted to the higher I class, telling them as soon as possible is better.

Comment: @shabunc Remember also, the date you make an online appointment serves as the date you fullfilled any time requirements.

Comment: Mark oh really! Gosh! I didn't knew that!

Comment: @shabunc It is a result of the fact that a registration that must be done within 10 days, needs an appointment that can take up to 8 weeks to get.